# How does EAP-SIM and RADIUS work together?

Tags: radius

I would like to know how does EAP-SIM and RADIUS work together.
Assume we have something like this:

```
[client-1]----+
              |
[client-2]----+----[AP]----------[RADIUS Server]------------[HSS]
              |
[client-3]----+

                                               |- Diameter -|
```

EAP-SIM and RADIUS should work between the client and the radius server, right?

Is one above the other? (like IP & TCP)

What is the content of the message(s) sent during the negocation(s) for both EAP-SIM and radius? (let's assume client-1 wants to connect and need to authenticate. The HSS is the component used by the RADIUS to check the 'credentials')

Comment: This belongs at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

The EAP SIM protocol operates between the client (supplicant) and the RADIUS server.  The RADIUS server will use the IMSI or ephemeral IMSI it got during the start of the EAP-SIM conversation to send a separate request to the HSS requesting authentication vectors.

The HSS will return multiple sets of UMTS quintuplets or GSM triplets.  The RADIUS server forwards the RAND component from a variable number of these vectors (2-3 in GSM) to the client, which feeds them to the SIM card to produce challenge responses.

The challenge responses and authentication vectors never go across the wire in plaintext, instead a PRF (Pseudo Random Function) is used to derive session keys. This derivation occurs on both the RADIUS server, and the client (supplicant).

If the SIM card does not produce the correct responses for the RAND challenge, then the session keys will not match and authentication will fail.

Note that if the HSS returns UMTS vectors, and EAP-SIM is being performed, there's a separate step to derive GSM vectors from the UMTS vectors.

Example code for the derivation is here: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v4.0.x/src/modules/rlm_eap/types/rlm_eap_sim/sim_vector.c#L157